# Meaning of "grounded" in a uniform field

Tags: electromagnetism

I am reading an example in a book which considers a grounded conductor inside a uniform electric field. The author stated that "grounded" means, as usual, \$V=0\$. But I am confused. 
In my opinion, "grounded" means having the same potential as the potential at infinity, which is usually set to zero. Now there is a uniform E field, and I don't think "grounded" still mean "same potential as at infinity. So what does it mean by a "grounded" conductor in this case?

Comment: How about a picture of what you mean?

Comment: How to post a picture? Sorry I am new.

Comment: Post the image somewhere public and give us the link. We'll upload it for you. Later, when you have enogh reputation points, you'll be able to do it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In my opinion, "grounded" means having the same potential as the potential at infinity,

This is a useful definition in a universe containing only a finite number of charged particles hanging in space, but it's not used much in practical engineering.

For example, in your example, there's a uniform field. If you go to infinity in one direction you will be at a very different potential than if you go to infinity in another direction (assuming you don't go in directions perpendicular to the field). So we really can't talk about the potential at infinity and a uniform field in all of space in the same example.

In this case, the author is telling you to take the grounded conductor as the reference potential, rather than a location at infinity. Just as a matter of facilitating communication (with whoever's grading your paper, for example) it's better to just use their convention than to make up your own. And in this case, the supplied convention is probably a good choice, given the difficulty I mentioned above.

Comment: So I can set $V$ equal to any constant in principle, not necessarily zero?

Comment: You can arbitrarily define your reference potential. If you call it "ground" people will think you mean 0 V. But in your example, you could arbitrarily say "I define ground to be 5 V below the potential on tis conductor" so that the conductor now has +5 V.